# list out of range 12

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to use BeautifulSoup4 to get the total number pages of the BBS.So I write this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup('A lot of HTML here', 'html.parser')
pagenumber = soup.find_all("div",class_="pagelinks")[0]
page_toatal_num = pagenumber.find_all("a")[-1].get_text()
print page_toatal_num
```

The elements of the page is here:
[image]

At this photo , I want to get "342",and by my way,I got it. But,what confusing is that,it raise the error:"list index out of range".In the cmd.exe, it both print the "342" but also raise the error. why?and how can I solve this problem

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 102, in iter_
errback
    yield next(it)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line
 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line
 22, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", li
ne 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 5
8, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "C:\python_workspace\deep_web\deep_web\spiders\deepSpider.py", line 73, i
n parse_item
    page_toatal_num = pagenumber.find_all("a")[-1].get_text()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: provide full `Traceback` from console please

Comment: I have provided the Traceback.